# Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. Using nodejs 18

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I followed the aws cdk [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/serverless_example.html#serverless_example_create_iam_function) to create an app. Everything is exactly the same with the code provided in the page. But after deploy, when I visite the gateway, I got this error in the cloudwatch:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1029:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1192:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1198:1"
    ]
}
```

I tried changing the file suffix to '.mjs', or use require, module.exports syntax, but I got another error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "widgets.main is undefined or not exported",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: widgets.main is undefined or not exported",
        "    at UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:15)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1192:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1198:1"
    ]
}
```

the code is in the tutorial page.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/serverless_example.html#serverless_example_create_iam_function

Comment: Could you push your code in a public git repo? I'd like to review